# C# Decryption of value from SQL Database using Hash Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, hash, cryptography

I'm using the code below provided by Microsoft for a Hash Algorithm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.8

What have been able to encrypt the password and save it to my SQL Database.

What I cannot do is retrieve the password from the SQL Database to compare it to an entered password by a user.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: A hash algorithm is a one-way operation. It is not possible to revert this operation. To check if an input is valid apply the same hash algorithm on it and compare the hashes.

Comment: You don't decrypt. You hash the provided password again and compare the hashes. You in fact *can't* decrypt. It's a one-way cryptographic function

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'll give it a try and I will let you know....

Comment: Apologies, trying to get my head around the logic.

So, if I use the hash algorithm, I can save the encrypted password at the line:

    encryptString = Convert.ToBase64String(edata1.ToArray());

Which would save something like 'a9l8t3+997bgQJAFOVzyaQ=='

But when the user enters his password, say the password is 'password'

The entered password is processed by the hash algorithm again.

But then how would it compare that it is the same encrypted password that is held on record?

Comment: The hashed password is stored in a database. So you can do a ´SELECT * FROM User WHERE usr = usr AND pass = hashedPass´ (something more refined, more likely) and if you get the user everything is good, if not they have to try again.

Comment: Also why store it as base64? Store it as `varbinary`. And there is no need to pass the hash back to the client with `SELECT * FROM User`, just do `SELECT 1 FROM User WHERE UserName = @usr AND PassHash = @hashedPass`

Comment: You never compare two passwords, you ***compare the password hashes*** instead.